# Accessing "other errors" from custom keyword code during validation time?

Tags: javascript, ajv

Can I check for previously generated validation errors, while validating the custom keyword?

This is the best I could come up with so far:

```
ajv.addKeyword('fromInput',{
  modifying:true,
  compile: function (schema, parentSchema, it){
    return function () {
      // console.log(it)
      return true;
    }
  },
  errors: true
});
```

Please note that I used the option to define "compile:" fn only because this option allows the "it" context, so from there I can access "it" or "it.self".

To be clear, and also to confirm that I interpreting this feature correctly (?), I placed the custom keyword as very last in the schema, so I assume that at validation time all previous keywords will be validated and errors generated.

So during validation of this custom keyword, I need to access those validation errors and make some decisions based on that.

However, I don't know where to go from here (see above code), because in the debugger I don't see any errors.

`it.self` does have an "errors" property, but it's `=null`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the author of ajv, "Only [inline keywords](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/CUSTOM.md#define-keyword-with-inline-compilation-function) have access to validation errors at the moment."

Here's a [link](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/300#issuecomment-247645840) to the comment and [another link](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/issues/486#issuecomment-300795940) mentioning the same thing.

Inline keywords also have access to 'it' which is the "Schema Compilation Context"